# perl socket client won't recognize end of message

Tags: perl, sockets, while-loop

I am running a simple perl socket client that queries a server, and then tries to close the socket once a keyword or phrase is encountered.

```
...
local $\ = "\x{0d}";
while($line = <$sock>){
  print $line."\n";
  last if ($line =~ /C6/);
}
...
close($sock);
```

I'd be happy to terminate on either the  (0x0d) or the "C6" string - they both terminate the message. I'm monitoring it with Wireshark, and both triggers occur at the end of the message, yet I can't break out of the while loop, either with a break or last, nor does $line ever print.

Ideas? TIA

Comment: I do have a timeout that eventually flushes the socket, but as this is an interactive application, I'd prefer the data sooner, but can't tighten the timeout for good cases due to occasional poor server communication environments. Using perl v5.18.2

Comment: When you say "_eventually flushes the socket_" do you mean that the `$line` does come?  Then -- what is `$sock`? Is it set to `autoflush` (or does each expected `$line` end with `\n`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the root of your problem here is that you've got `$\` set, which is the output record separator, rather than `$/` which is the input record separator.

So your `while` is waiting for a `\n` to occur before handing `$line` onto the rest of the loop.

But failing that, there's also a question of buffering and autoflushing on your socket.

And ... when you say you're monitoring with wireshark, how sure are you that those values are part of the packet content payload rather than part of the packet? Do you actually get `\n` sent from the server as part of the packet at any point?

Answer (score 1):

You don't exit when you receive `C6` without receiving a Carriage Return (or EOF) because your code always waits for a Carriage Return (or EOF). Fix:

```
# sysread returns as soon as data is available, so this is a just a maximum.
use constant BLOCK_SIZE => 4*1024*1024;

my $buf = '';
while (1) {
   my $rv = sysread($sock, $buf, length($buf), 4*1024*1024);
   die($!) if !defined($rv);
   last if !$rv;

   process_message($1)
      while $buf =~ s/^( (?: [^C\x0D] | C (?=[^6]) )*+ (?: C6 | \x0D ) )//xs;
}

die("Premature EOF") if length($buf);
```

Comment: Huh. I tried that and died of a premature EOF, even with a small buffer size. ($rv is not defined)

Comment: That means there's was stuff after the end of the message (after the CR or the `C6`)

Comment: wow - that was fast! Yes, there's an x0D. Actually, a more clearly defined end might be R02...C6\n.

Comment: No idea what "R02..C6\n" means, but feel free to adjust

Comment: It's the complete termination string; it occurred to me that C6 may occur in the "natural" data being returned.